# Windows 10 directory Installer takes too much space, can I set it as compressed folder?

Tags: configuration, windows-10, maintenance

Windows 10 directory Installer takes too much space - 41 GB.

First I have problem with Microsoft search which has 31 GB. I manage to reset it. Then I upgraded to Windows 10. After 1 month I deleted old installation files and I have almost 70 GB free. Yesterday I see that I have 17 GB. I did not installed some major software except updates.

I found that this is system folder and I cannot empty it, but can I set is as compressed folder to free space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the **Disk Cleanup** tool for proper removal. You need to tick the Windows Installation Files checkbox. You may have to select "Clean up system files".

> To delete temporary files:
>
> - Search for Disk cleanup from the taskbar and select it from the list of results.
> - Under Files to delete, select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> - Select OK.
>
> If you need to free up more space, you can also delete system files:
>
> - In Disk cleanup, select Clean up system files.
> - Select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> - Select OK.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/8fef4121-711b-4be1-996f-99e02c7301c2/disk-cleanup-in-windows-10

Comment: I already do that. I have a main problem. First I have problem with Microsoft search which has 31 GB. I manage to reset it. Then I upgraded to Windows 10. After 1 month I deleted old installation files and I have almost 70 GB free. Yesterday I see that I have 17 GB. I did not installed some major software except updates. I check and see that there is no such box. I check also in "Cleanup System files" section.

Comment: Why do you tell us this only now? If you just said this in the beginning, you would not have wasted my time writing a useless answer.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, I don't mean to waist your time. I will update my answer.